What is XX/YY/ZZ-interaction (or coupling)?
I see this term is used in many places [1,2,3,4]. I feel that it is about the $\sigma_{x/y/z}\otimes\sigma_{x/y/z}$ term in the Hamiltonian, but even I take this interpretation, I don't understand sentences like (between page 2 and 3 in [4])

...the coupling between the two qubits in the computational subspace
(dressed basis) is ZZ, but it originates from the transverse XX
coupling between level $|11\rangle$ and the higher levels $|20\rangle$
and $|02\rangle$.

Can anyone give a further explanation on the term, especially on the sentence I quoted?

The XX interaction is the interaction
$$
h = J_{xx} (\sigma_x\otimes \sigma_x + \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y)\ .
$$
The name refers to the fact that the two terms have the same strength. Correspondingly, the XY interaction is of the form
$$
h = J_{x} \sigma_x\otimes \sigma_x + J_y\sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y\ ,
$$
the XXZ interaction of the form
$$
h = J_{xx} (\sigma_x\otimes \sigma_x + \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y)+
J_z\sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z\ ,
$$
and so on.

I am not sure about the generalization. Can $XX$-interaction be $H=J(\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x+\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z)$ or is it a $ZZ$-interaction? Then how about $H=J(\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y+\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z)$? A $YY$-interaction?

I've never seen the examples you give named. All the examples I give I've seen, and consider it the common use of the term (including XXX interaction). And yes, there's no definition or anything like that, it's a physicists' usage.

Thanks. But still I am not sure about the generalization of the naming. Can you give an explicit example of a $ZZ$-interaction? Or is it just $J\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z$?

Do you have a reference where the term "ZZ interaction" is used?

Hi. I attached 4 links to the question. Maybe the 4th link contains sophisticated uses, as that is the manuscript's theme.

The quote you give certainly does not contain the phrase "ZZ interaction".

I meant links not quotes, and this is the link if there was confusion: https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.13292.

I suspect they mean an Ising coupling in the Z basis, but I would consider calling that "ZZ interaction" (rather than "ZZ coupling" or the like) a non-standard usage, which should be defined. The standardized uses in condensed matter would be, as far as I can tell, XX, XY, XXX, XXZ, and XYZ, in analogy to what I gave above. All others are non-standard in a CM context, and I am unaware that there is a broadly accepted standard usage outside of condensed matter.
